# Matlab equivalent for numpy allclose?

Tags: matlab, floating-point, comparison, floating-accuracy

Numpy's [allclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) *Returns True if two arrays are element-wise equal within a tolerance*.

Is there any equivalent in Matlab?

Answer (score 6):

Not that I know of. But its description

> If the following equation is element-wise True, then allclose returns True.
>
> absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))

is very easy to mimic in Matlab:

```
all( abs(a(:)-b(:)) <= atol+rtol*abs(b(:)) )
```

where `a` and `b` are the arrays (same shape, arbitrary number of dimensions), `atol` is absolute tolerance and `rtol` is relative tolerance.

If you also want to specifically check that the shapes are the same:

```
isequal(size(a), size(b)) && all( abs(a(:)-b(:)) <= atol+rtol*abs(b(:)) )
```

---

**Note**: you **should not** be using NumPy's default `rtol` and `atol`, by their own admission. Refer to [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10161) .

Comment: In the last two releases of MATLAB you can do `all(...,'all')`, avoids the need of `(:)` indexing.

Comment: I hope the note is fine. I'll repeat here with more detail just in case: you **should not** be using NumPy's default `rtol` and `atol`, by their own admission. Refer to [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10161) (latest comments are most relevant); current consensus is on `rtol=1e-9` for double precision, and `atol=0` is better but won't work for data containing zeros, in which case I recommend `atol=1e-15` for data on order of 1 (`mean(abs(x)) ~= 1`).